# Length of jQuery collection object doesn't change after calling detach() on an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

This seems incredibly simple but I *cannot* understand why it doesn't work.

```
$('.some-containers').each(function () {

    var $ul = $(this).find('ul');

    var $items = $ul.find('li'); 
    console.log($items.length); //5

    if ($items.length > 2) {
        var $last = $items.last().detach();
        console.log($items.length); //still 5
    }

}
```

My question is why, after removing or detaching the last item, is the last item still there?

Comment: It's how `.detach` works, isn't it? "The .detach() method is the same as .remove(), except that .detach() keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements." It keeps it in the set but removes it from the dom so you can easily re-insert it later.

Comment: .last().remove() does the same thing - still 5

Comment: jQuery objects does not have any reference with DOM elements. detach will remove and return the last element.  But the jquery object will stay unmodified. If you want to know the new length, then again you need to query the DOM .

Comment: ah so i have to query the dom repeatedly?

Comment: @userqwert Yes. You have to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of `$items` as a copy of the element collection in the DOM, instead of a reference. `detach()` operates on the DOM, and removes the specified element from the DOM.

Reassign `$items` to the collection again:

```
$items = $ul.find('li');
```

or just do `$ul.find('li').length` and the length will reflect the actual value.

Example (thanks @MartinGottweis): https://jsfiddle.net/j7hqnhb3/